# Why HTTP POST request in Node application require refresh while submitting form data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Angular Code

```
.state('studentInfo.newStudent', {
          url : '/new/student',
          templateUrl: 'students/new-student.html',
          controller : function($state, $http){
            this.saveStudent = function(student){
                $http({method: 'POST', url: `/studentInfo/new`, data: {student}}).then(function(){
                    $state.go('studentInfo');
      });
```

Express Code

```
app.post('/studentInfo/new', jsonParser, (request, response)=>{
   let students = mongoUtil.students();
   let newStudent = request.body.student;
   students.save(newStudent, (err, res) =>{
     if(err){
       res.sendStatus(400);
         }
     res.sendStatus(201);
      });
  });
```

My question these code is working for saving data while submitting an Angular form. But it will require an refresh to see my update on

```
http://localhost:8181/#!/studentinfo
```

still I could provide a state to go on 'studentinfo'.
What the changes require to update the list in 'studentinfo' route to see my current saved data without hit a browser refresh

Comment: You could return the newly updated data when you save data and update it right away in your view

Comment: Please write code for same

Answer (score 2):

If you return data while sending the response and data in json and parse it using Angular and show on view.

You have to return newstudent variable while sending 201 in response in the case of success.

If you want me to write code please mention in comment below my answer

Comment: Yes please write code for better understanding what would you provide solution for this problem.